# How can I use a constant to enter multiple @CrossOrigins?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cors, spring-annotations

I have a `@CrossOrigin` annotation on several of my controllers.  I'd like to be able to set a `static final` somewhere and have all of them refer to it.  Something like:

```
public static final String[] ORIGINS = {"domain1","domain2"};
...
@CrossOrigin(origins = ORIGINS)
```

However, I clearly have some syntax off.

**Solution**
For those who are interested in doing the same thing, here's what I did:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@CrossOrigin(origins = {
        "domain1",
        "domain2"
})
@Controller
@interface CORSPermittedController {
}
```

That allows me to annotate all my controllers with `@CORSPermittedController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that with Java syntax. Attribute values must be compile constants (primitive, `String` literals, or arrays of these types).

But you could write a bean post processor which is responsible for putting this annotation over a class at runtime by using [javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/).

Comment: Right!  That was the part I was missing.  Actually, rather than using `javassist`, a better way is to use Spring's ability to use meta-annotations and create my own.  That also achieves the "change it in one place" goal.

Answer (score -1):

public static final String[] ORIGINS = {"DOMAIN1","DOMAIN2"};

Try that, the constants should be capitalized. The reason why they are constants is because you're declaring them as final. So, they have to be capitalized.

If that doesn't work try

public static final String[] ORIGINS = {"DOMAINONE","DOMAINTWO"};

OR

The other way you can create constants is

public enum Origins {DOMAIN1,DOMAIN2}

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't make any sense. And it does not answer the question.